Proving a function is constant given it is continuous (Mean Value Theorem)
I have the following function, $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which is a continuous function such that $f(x) = f(x(2−x))$, for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $f$ is constant on $[0, 2]$.
I understand this is using the mean value theorem and considering the derivative equal to zero for $f$. Can anyone help me with how to set out this proof?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

The mean-value theorem is only applicable if $f$ is  assumed to be differentiable.

Hint: Consider the sequence defined by $a_0 = x$, $a_{n+1} = a_n(2-a_n)$. What can you say about $f(a_n)$ and $\lim a_n$?

This sequence converges. Can you please provide more guidance. Thank you!

Try and see if you can work out what the sequence converges to.

I gave found that the function coverages to either 0 or 1 depending on the input of x. If 0 < x < 1, it  converges to 1. If  1 < x < 2 it converges to 0. As they are converging to different values, how do I prove this function is constant?

@AbbeyW: One of those values is wrong.

The orbit of $x \to 2x - x^2$ starting from any $x \in [0, 2]\setminus\{1\}$ converges to $0$, as can be seen by, say, a cobweb diagram argument.
Thus using continuity, we get that $f(x) = f(0)$ for any $x \in [0, 2]\setminus\{1\}$, and by continuity again $f$ is constant on the whole interval as desired.

Are you sure? Unless I am mistaken, the orbit of any starting point in $[0,2] \setminus { 1 }$ converges to $0$.

@Martin R Oh, whoops I think I drew the diagram wrongly… let me see if I remember how to complete the square correctly.

@MartinR I get that it converges to $0$ starting from any point in $(0, 1)$, and to $2$ from any point in $(1, 2)$. And fortuitously, we have $f(0) = f(2)$ from the relationship, so we get that $f$ is constant as desired.

$x \mapsto 2x - x^2$ maps $(1, 2)$ to $(0, 1)$, so the orbit of starting points in $(1, 2)$ converges to $0$ as well.

Ah you are right.
